# Symfony2 remember me not working when session expires

Tags: php, symfony, session, cookies

I've made login form and now I want create remember me functionality. Using symfony 2 documentation I added parameters to security.yml file, next fill form with remember me checkbox. Next step was cookie set when user logging in. I thought everything is ok, but when I remove PHPSESSID cookie or session ends, user is logged out from website. I thing symfony not checking REMEMBERME cookie when session expires. I'm new in symfony and don't know how fix it.
[Here is my gist with security.yml, login form and SecurityController that extends FOSUserBundle SecurityController](https://gist.github.com/miedzwin/6c84a5cceac376423ed8)

Comment: So look at the cookie, check it has an appropriate timeout set

Comment: After login I have two cookies: http://imgur.com/DBCt5IC
If i remove PHPSESSID and press refresh, I'm redirected to login form, cookie REMEMBERME is also removed ane new PHPSESSID cookie is set, also I'm logged out.